# How to insert a new row in Material-UI?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I'm developing a contacts application where all data is stored on client-side temporarily. I've used material-ui table to display the contacts.

[image: Screenshot]

When add new contact button on the bottom right is clicked it displays a Dialog with a form in it. When save button is clicked the data is saved in the state. But the problem I'm facing is how to insert a new row within the table with the form data in it. I searched for it but I couldn't find even a single query regarding the same. The add new contact button is in `AddContact` component and table is in `Contacts` component but both have same parent component which is in `Main`. So in a nutshell I'm not able to display the new contact in the table.

Comment: Could you give us component structure?

Comment: @sudobangbang I've already mentioned the structure of the components in my question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maintain an `array` in `state` variable, when you click on submit in Dialog, push that data in `state array`. Use the `array` to generate the rows dynamically, like this:

```
<Table>
    <TableHeader>
        <TableRow>
            /*Define the headers*/
        </TableRow>
    </TableHeader>
    <TableBody>
        {this._generateRows()}
    </TableBody>
</Table>
```

Write the `_generateRows` function like this to generate the rows:

```
_generateRows(){
  return this.state.data.map(el => {
    return <TableRow>
              <TableRowColumn>{el.a}</TableRowColumn>
              <TableRowColumn>{el.b}</TableRowColumn>
              <TableRowColumn>{el.c}</TableRowColumn>
          </TableRow>
    })
}
```

Reference : [Material-UI table](http://www.material-ui.com/#/components/table).

**Note:** Replace **el.a, el.b, el.c** with the original data.

Answer (score 0):

I see you are using react. This means that when you bind a list of items to the 
row components in your render function.

```
{list.map(item => <RowComponent key={item.id}/>)}
```

Now when you click the button all you have to do is `push` to this list and your new row is rendered on screen.

Comment: Please do not mutate state variables directly, for example with `push`. Use component's [`setState`](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#setstate) or state management library like [Redux](http://redux.js.org) to avoid issues with components not rendering at all or rendering with the old state.

Comment: You are correct. React works best when you re-create the array. So when pushing you could first clone the array. with splice() for instance, and then push the item. or use a lib like Redux, but then you should also make a new copy of the array before adding the item. The change detection mechanisme of React checks the reference of a given object if they are the same React considers it as not changed.